# Sunpy old version? module 'sunpy.net.vso.attrs' has no attribute 'Time'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code to download SDO data with the following script, but it get an attribute error. I am not sure why and can't find this error discussed online.

`AttributeError: module 'sunpy.net.vso.attrs' has no attribute 'Time'`

code

```
from sunpy.net import vso
client = vso.VSOClient()

mydir = '.'

qr = client.search(vso.attrs.Time('2018/06/12 09:34:28', '2018/06/12 09:35:28'), vso.attrs.Instrument('hmi'))

print(qr)

resp = input('Press [y] to download and [n] to exit')
if resp == 'y':
    print('Downloading ...')
    res = client.fetch(qr, path=mydir+'/{file}').wait()
else:
    print('END')
    pass
print('END')
```

edit:

i found the source code, and it should parse time i think.
https://github.com/sunpy/sunpy/blob/main/sunpy/net/vso/attrs.py

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and putting the answer here in case someone (including me) ever comes across this problem. Replace client by Fido

https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/guide/acquiring_data/jsoc.html